# How to insert image into octopress framework?

Tags: markdown, octopress

I have image terminal.png on directory /Users/tragicidea/Desktop/terminal.png. I want to insert that image on my post using this script

```
{% img /Users/tragicidea/Desktop/terminal.png %}
```

but my image does not appear on my post, what should I do?

Answer (score 39):

copy your image in Octopress/source/images.

PS: Octopress(whatever you named it) directory is a repository directory for your blog.

then you can use img tag as

`{% img left /images/terminal.png 350 350 'image' 'images' %}`

Answer (score 9):

you should check this out:
http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/image-tag/

example:

`{% img center http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/image-files/avatar-6.jpg  %}`